# C++ error C2664 from part of a code

Tags: c++

Getting error C2664 here:

```
void GetSkyrimSearchString(std::string & search_string){
    char output[256]; 
    GetPrivateProfileString("Loader", "RuntimeName", "TESV.exe",
        &output[0], 256, ".\\Data\\SKSE\\skse.ini");
    search_string = std::string(&output[0]);
}
```

Comment: Which line is producing the error? Can you post the full error?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5b150wd.aspx

Comment: GetPrivateProfileString("Loader", "RuntimeName", "TESV.exe",
        &output[0], 256, ".\\Data\\SKSE\\skse.ini"); That line lol

`Error 1 error C2664: 'DWORD GetPrivateProfileStringW(LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPWSTR,DWORD,LPCWSTR)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [7]' to 'LPCWSTR' C:\Users\Alan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SkyrimOnline-master\Src\Skyrim.Script\dllmain.cpp 8 1 Skyrim.Script

Answer (score 0):

GetPrivateProfileString(_T("Loader"), _T("RuntimeName"), _T("TESV.exe"),
        &output[0], 256, _T(".\Data\SKSE\skse.ini"));